# Django REST nested serializers

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django and Django Rest here.

I created 3 models (see below).

I'm able to create some easy and basic serializers for each of those models, but I would like to create a more complex serializer for the `CustomUser` models than returns for each user it's roles.

I've read the "Serializer relations" section in the doc. It's still not very clear how to achieve it.

In the examples they uses 2 models relations, but if I'm not wrong, I have 3, making things more complicated for me to understand.

Could someone give me some tips to do it?

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    class Meta:
        db_table = "MyUsers"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Roles(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=100,related_name="roles_label")
    class Meta:
        db_table = "roles"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.label

class RolesUsers(models.Model):
    id_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,related_name="id_user", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_role = models.ForeignKey(Roles, related_name="id_role", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "roles_users"
        unique_together = (("id_user", "id_role"),)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {}'.format(self.id_role, self.id_user)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

related name should be meaning full name

```
class RolesUsers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,related_name="user_role", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Roles, related_name="user_role", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "roles_users"
        unique_together = (("id_user", "id_role"),)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {}'.format(self.id_role, self.id_user)
```

you can create user serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializers):
   class Meta:
         model = CustomUser
         fields = ('id', 'user_role', 'email', 'username')
```